# What are some examples of Jewish names?

Tags: names, etymology

What are Jewish sounding names that come from various occupations and locations? Please give the "rough" translation and background too.

Comment: @Moshe What do you mean by "occupations and locations"? Are you asking for any and all Jewish names, their meanings and origins?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12527.

Comment: you mean surname correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following links may be of interest:

- http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Jewish_surnames
- http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_surnames_from_German
- http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_surnames_from_Hebrew
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_surnames

Answer (score 5):

Kohen, Cohen, Coen, Katz etc.= families of kohanim

Levi, Levy, Weill, Segal = families of leviyim

Comment: It is said that Katz is an acronym for Kohen Tzedek and Segel for Segan Leviim.

Comment: @YDK Is there evidence of those names being acronyms?

Comment: cube, yes. There are many manuscripts and early printed seforim in which both these names appear and there is a " in between the kof and tzadi of Katz, as well as between the gimel and lamed of Segal. These clearly indicates that they are acronyms. One example would be the seforim of the Shach, in which, although he was known by the last name Katz, he is called "Kohein Tzedek. e.g http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45712&pgnum=1

Comment: And then see here http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41340&pgnum=1

Comment: Notice that only 9 years later Kohein Tzedek has become Katz. The Salonika print is in Tav Kuf Samech Alef and the Lvov print is in Tav Kuf Ayin.

Answer (score 4):

Kramer = storekeeper

Wasserman = water carrier

Kentof = Kohain Tov

Klein = small