# Does a Kohen have to be concerned about the surname of a potential mate?

Tags: names, marriage, kohen-priest, genealogy

In [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/which-surnames-are-exclusively-kohanims-and-why) various surnames are explored that are strongly associated with being a Kohein. Some of them are rather unambiguously chosen simply because the chooser wanted to indicate their status. Others are more coincidental in nature (e.g. Rappaport), and some are contra-indicators (e.g. Hadad).

For a name that pretty strongly indicates Kohen lineage, if a Kohen is suggested a shidduch with a woman who has such a maiden last name (eg "Katz," "Cohen" or maybe especially "Hadad") but whose family has no claim of being Kohanim or any knowledge of how the family came to possess that name, should he be concerned that the family was in fact a family of Kohanim and then became [Chalalim](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/01/09/chalalim-kohen-married-to-divorcee/), or should he just regard the name as a coincidence?

Comment: Is a _kohen_ not allowed to marry the daughter of a _chalal_?

Comment: @msh210, from my link on Chalalim: "For female children, the daughter (a chalalah) can marry anyone except for a Kohen."

Comment: Yishai @msh210 A Chalala who marries a Yisrael ends the line. This is all discussed in EH 7:16

Comment: @DoubleAA, thanks, but that's not relevant, as that'd end the surname line also.